# Shifting a set of points and get new coordinates?

Tags: qgis

I have a transect that I've added as a delimited text layer that has UTM X and Y coordinates for about 300 points all within a river meander.
[image: red points in a line that run on land instead of lining up with river channel]
 They currently do not line up with the channel shown in the raster, so I would like to use the selection tool to highlight and shift them, just like the first ~1 min of this video for QGIS 2.8.2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiihopTnewg

When I select this layer, I am not able to toggle editing. I cannot seem to find the reason why. Once I do move these points, will I be able to export the new coordinates? Is there a better way to do this, considering I have about 20 transects to shift from 0.4-3m?
Example of coordinates:

[image: UTM X: 4310006.696, UTM Y: 330900.7821]

(hi I'm very new, apologies if this should be obvious)

edit: I'm using QGIS 3.6.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. I assume you are using this data for scientific research? Then tampering with your data (or shifting) is a No-Go! Rather use a different ortophoto which uses a CRS similar to the one your data is in - this should reduce the differences. Also note that in remote areas ortophotos tend to be older and sometimes a bit misaligned..

Comment: Another possibility is that the river has actually shifted since the photo was taken. In that case the solution would be to get a more recent photo.

Answer (score 2):

As Erik says, manually shifting your data might not be a good idea. If you really need to...

1. Export your delimited text layer to a Geopackage or shapefile (this is why you can't toggle editing). Right'click on the layer in the 'Layers' panel > Export > Save features as...
2. Toggle editing on your new layer, select the points you want to move and use the 'Move feature' editing function.
3. The coordinates in your attribute table will not update automatically. To update these, open the attribute table of your layer and open field calculator,  and either update the existing fields or create new ones for the new coordinates. The expressions $x and $y can be used in field calculator to get x and y coordinates from point geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the help! (also I am shifting copied versions of the data for a working example for myself, original data will not be manipulated!)